# Packaged project not opening in windows

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am attempting to create a Halloween style game for a competition I am entering, however once I have packaged it and the Windows No Editor folder is created, I double click on the exe program to open it. The blue, circular loading symbol appears for a few seconds before disappearing and doing nothing. I have noticed that the executable file is only 183KB large. For a 3 level game I expected it to be bigger.

Here is what my packaging settings are:[image: My packaging settings]

(I have also tried setting the "Use Pak File" to false which just makes a blank window)

The warnings I get when I am packaging are:                                          LogLinker: Warning: Failed to load Game/2DSideScrollerBP/2DSideScrollerOverview': Can't find file.   (I shouldn't be using this file as it is a 3D game that I am making)
LogLinker: Warning: Failed to load '/Game/2DSideScrollerBP/2DSideScrollerOverview': Can't find file.
LogUObjectGlobals: Warning: Failed to find object 'Class /Game/2DSideScrollerBP/2DSideScrollerOverview.2DSideScrollerOverview_C'    UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogReflectionCaptureComponent: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/LakeWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogReflectionCaptureComponent: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/LakeWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogReflectionCaptureComponent: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/LakeWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogReflectionCaptureComponent: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/LakeWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogReflectionCaptureComponent: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/LakeWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogReflectionCaptureComponent: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/OceanWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogReflectionCaptureComponent: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/OceanWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogReflectionCaptureComponent: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/OceanWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogReflectionCaptureComponent: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/OceanWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LogReflectionCaptureComponent: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/OceanWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
PackagingResults: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/LakeWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
PackagingResults: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/LakeWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
PackagingResults: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/LakeWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
PackagingResults: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/LakeWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
PackagingResults: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/LakeWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
PackagingResults: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/OceanWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
PackagingResults: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/OceanWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
PackagingResults: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/OceanWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
PackagingResults: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/OceanWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.
PackagingResults: Warning: /Game/WaterPlane/Maps/OceanWater_Example contains a legacy UReflectionCaptureComponent and is being non-deterministically cooked - please resave the asset and recook.                                I have tried saving the asset and repackaging but this message still appears.         I don't know if this changes anything though. Is it possible that it may have something to do with the settings I am using?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound as though any of your assets were cooked or packaged. First thing I would recommend is to check [Epic's Unreal packaging documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Basics/Projects/Packaging/index.html) and ensure that you've followed the steps. Then, when packaging, watch your log and ensure that it's not throwing warnings or errors as it tries to package the project.

Comment: I have tried resetting the packaging settings to default. This just makes a blank window appear which I can only shut down via task manager. The file size has stayed the same.